According to the Majority of Jurists Within the 4 Madhabs, Does a Dhimmi Have a Right to Self Defense Against Belligerent Muslims?
For example, if it's proven that a Muslim was physically oppressing a Dhimmi, and a Dhimmi physically defended himself, would the Dhimmi be punished for that?
